# Test suspendCoroutine with Mockk library

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

I had a function and a unit test which worked but when I added a `suspendCoroutine` - a unit test starts to fail.
Here a simplified versions of them:

```
fun loginOld() {
    logInUseCase.execute(
        LogInUseCase.Params("email", "password"), viewModelScope,
        onResult = { result ->
            //do something with loginResult
        }
    )
}
```

Unit test using `Mockk` library

```
    @Test
    fun `Test login`() = runTest {

    val onResultLogin = slot<(AuthorizedResponse?) -> Unit>()
    coJustRun {
        logInUseCase.execute(
            any(),
            any(),
            any(),
            onResult = capture(onResultLogin),
            onError = any()
        )
    }

    viewModel.loginOld()//or viewModel.loginNew()

    val responseAuthorized = AuthorizedResponse(
        "access",
        .......
    )

    onResultLogin.captured.invoke(responseAuthorized)

    advanceUntilIdle()
    
    coVerify {
        logInUseCase.execute(
            any(),
            any(),
            any(),
            onResult = capture(onResultLogin),
            onError = any()
        )
    }

}
```

This combination works perfectly. Now new version of a login function using `suspendCoroutine`

```
fun loginNew() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val loginParams = LogInUseCase.Params("email", "password")
        val loginResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { loginUseCase(loginParams) }
        //do something with loginResult
    }
}

private suspend fun loginUseCase(params: LogInUseCase.Params): AuthorizedResponse {
    return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        logInUseCase.execute(params, viewModelScope, showErrorOnUI = false,
            onResult = { authorizedResponse ->
                continuation.resume(authorizedResponse)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Unit test with function `loginNew` fails with message

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property captured has not been initialized
```

at point `onResultLogin.captured.invoke(responseAuthorized)`

What to do to pass this test?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
    @Test
    fun `Test login`() = runTest {

    val responseAuthorized = AuthorizedResponse(..)
    val onResultLogin = slot<(AuthorizedResponse?) -> Unit>()
    coEvery {
        logInUseCase.execute(
            any(),
            any(),
            any(),
            onResult = capture(onResultLogin),
            onError = any()
        )
    } coAnswers {
        onResultLogin.captured.invoke(responseAuthorized)
    }

    viewModel.loginNew()

    advanceUntilIdle()

    coVerify {
        logInUseCase.execute(
            any(),
            any(),
            any(),
            onResult = capture(onResultLogin),
            onError = any()
        )
    }
}
```

I use `coEvery` instead of `coJustRun` to call `onResultLogin.captured.invoke` in `coAnswers`

and a top of this test class looks like this:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class LoginViewModelTest {
private val logInUseCase: LogInUseCase = mockk()
private lateinit var viewModel: LoginViewModel

@get:Rule
val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

@get:Rule
val mainDispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()

@Before
fun setup() = runTest {
    Dispatchers.setMain(UnconfinedTestDispatcher())

    viewModel = LoginViewModel(logInUseCase)
}
```

where this line `Dispatchers.setMain(UnconfinedTestDispatcher())` is very important